# List relation name from n path cypher query

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

I have country to district nodes

```
       [:relation]          [:relation]           [:relation]

    A----country---------B-----state---------C-----district-------D

(name=India)        (name=Delhi)         (name=xyz)           (name=abc)
```

I want to get relation name between each nodes

country state district....

I tried this query i want to traverse 1 to 6 nodes

```
match p=(n:test10{name:"india"})-[relations:has*1..6]->(m:test10) 
return distinct m.parameter as parameter,m.name as name,
       filter(r IN relations WHERE r.relation <> 'none');
```

but am not getting correct result 
kindly help me on the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`extract`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-extract) :

```
extract(rel in relations | type(rel))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Cypher should work if all the nodes you care about have the `test10` label, all the relationships you care about have the `has` type, and all those relationships store the name value using the `relation` property.